# expose c3po dataSourceName in jmx

Tags: java, c3p0

Is there a way to make c3p0 to register to jmx with its dataSourceName? Currently my c3p0 data create a random name to register to jmx even though it has its dataSourceName. For example my configuration in spring is:

```
<bean id="services" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="dataSourceName" value="mySQLDataSource"/>
  <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl">
    <value>${jdbcUrl}</value>
   </property>
  <property name="user">
    <value>${user}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="password">
   <value>${password}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" />
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="maxIdleTime" value="10" />
  </property>
 </bean>11
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if C3P0 allows that, but that feature is present in BoneCP (http://jolbox.com).

Comment: Do you know any large projects using BoneCP?

Comment: This being an open source project, tracking is hard. However we use it internally in several large projects including an affiliate system and a credit-card transaction system, both being mission-critical web-apps taking millions of hits.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible!

I've gotten it working with the .properties file, myself, but the documentation says it will also work with an XML file.

With your Spring approach it might be less confusing to make a properties file.

Mine is at webapps/[appname]/WEB-INF/classes/c3p0.properties

References:
 - http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management
 - http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#c3p0_conf